# How to sort and slice an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

I have an array of shots. I have been able to take that array and loop through it to get all shots that occurred on hole #1 and then rearrange them in order based on "shot_number". I now need to do this for every hole and to create an array for each hole (ex: holeArray1, holeArray2). I have attempted a number of solutions to increment x but if I do I end up missing some shots that occurred on certain holes.

How can I refactor this function to create this array for every hole without just copying and pasting the code and changing the variable x myself? Thank you for your help. I know I should be able to figure this one out but am struggling.

```
  $scope.createHoleShotsArrays = function () {
    var i = 0;
    var x = 1;
    var holeArray = [];
    var len = $scope.shots.length;
    for (; i < len; i++) {
        if ($scope.shots[i].attributes.hole == x) {
            holeArray.push($scope.shots[i]);
            holeArray.sort(function (a, b) {
                if (a.attributes.shot_number > b.attributes.shot_number) {
                    return 1;
                }
                if (a.attributes.shot_number < b.attributes.shot_number) {
                    return -1;
                }
                // a must be equal to b
                return 0;
            });
        }
    }
    console.log(holeArray);
};
```

Comment: Sorting an array inside a loop is definitely not what you want to do. Push the items you want on the array and then sort *once* outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push the items you want into arrays, and sort them once. I don't have cases to test the code. You may modified it a little if something goes wrong.

```
$scope.createHoleShotsArrays = function() {
  var holeArrays = [];
  $scope.shots.forEach(function(shot) {
    if (holeArrays.length < shot.attributes.hole) {
      holeArrays[shot.attributes.hole - 1] = [];
    }
    holeArrays[shot.attributes.hole - 1].push(shot);
  });

  holeArrays.forEach(function(arr) {
    arr.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.attributes.shot_number - b.attributes.shot_number;
    });
  });

  console.log(holeArrays);
};
```

Comment: much more elegant than anything I would have come up with.